# gestureScanner functions overrides hyperlinks click

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink, gesture

I have a problem with hyperlinks in the webview. I have gone over all the links that addresses similar issue, but haven't find any addressing the same issue.

I have a custom web view, which implements some actions on certain gesture. I guess this is disabling the touch for the hyperlinks.

How can I keep the gestures and enable the hyperlinks to work and call shouldOverrideUrlLoading?

This is the custom web view I have:

```
public class newBTWebView extends WebView implements QuickAction.OnDismissListener, PopoverView.PopoverViewDelegate, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
public newBTWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.ctx = context;
    setup(context);
    init(context);

}

public newBTWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.ctx = context;
    setup(context);
    init(context);

}

public void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    setInitialScale(100);
    this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();

    int screenLayout = 1;
    try
    {
        Field field = conf.getClass().getDeclaredField("screenLayout");
        screenLayout = field.getInt(conf);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }

    loadingNewChap = false;

    screenType = screenLayout & 15;

    gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
    this.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    this.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);


    this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                countDown++;
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP  && isLongPress)
            {
                 //do selection

            }
            return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
}
```

I have also implemented the gesture's functions: onFlingDo, onSingleTapUp, onShowPress, onLongPress, onDown

This is how I call the webview in the activity:

```
testWV = (newBTWebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview1);
testWV.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
testWV.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

testWV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
     {
           super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
           return false;
     }

     @Override
     public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     }
}
```

How can I keep the gestures and still capture the hyperlinks clicks?

Comment: dear down voters, kindly on down voting state the reason behind it so I may fix it. thank you.

Comment: Since you asked: the downvotes are probably for the unnecessary edit war. Good edits should always be kept, unless they change the meaning of the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            countDown++;
        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP  && isLongPress)
        {
             //do selection

        }
        gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```

in onTouch callback, return false to implement default touch behavior.

Comment: I will try the following and get back to you, thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this below code it will solve the issue :

```
testWV .setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
testWV .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
testWV .getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
testWV .loadUrl(url); 
testWV .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
  view.loadUrl(url);
  return true;
}
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, kindly note that the hyperlinks are not even clicking to call this function shouldOverrideUrlLoading